# node_type_get_type() and hook_uninstall()

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a job_post module, which defines the "job_post" content type.

In this module I have `hook_unistall()` which calls [node_type_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_delete/7) to remove that content type.

After uninstalling, I have the following error from the Comment module:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_node_type_delete() (line 343 of ....\comment.module).

I have this error because the `$info` variable in `node_type_delete()` is set to `FALSE`.

Why when my module is installed and when I am printing `var_dump(node_type_get_type('job_post'))` on any page, I have an object, but when I'm trying to print the same code in my unistall function I get `FALSE` and this error?

#### job_post.install

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function job_post_install() {
  node_types_rebuild();

  $types = node_type_get_types();
  node_add_body_field($types['job_post']);

  $body_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'job_post');
  $body_instance['type'] = 'text_summary_or_trimmed';

  field_update_instance($body_instance);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */
function job_post_uninstall() {
  $instances = field_info_instances('node', 'job_post');
  foreach ($instances as $instance_name => $instance) {
    field_delete_instance($instance);
  }

  // Force rebuild of the node type cache
  // as Clive suggested didn't help
  // _node_types_build(TRUE);

  node_type_delete('job_post');

  field_purge_batch(1000);
}
```

#### job_post.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_info() to provide our job_post type.
 */
function job_post_node_info() {
  return array(
    'job_post' => array(
      'name' => t('Job Post'),
      'base' => 'job_post',
      'description' => t('Use this content type to post a job.'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => t('Job Title'),
      'help' => t('Enter the job title and job description')
    )
  );
}

/**
 * Implement hook_form() with the standard default form.
 */
function job_post_form($node, $form_state) {
  return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code that the Forum module executes in [forum_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum.install/function/forum_uninstall/7), you will notice that it just deletes the field it defines, but it doesn't delete the content type it defines.

```
function forum_uninstall() {
  // Load the dependent Taxonomy module, in case it has been disabled.
  drupal_load('module', 'taxonomy');

  variable_del('forum_containers');
  variable_del('forum_hot_topic');
  variable_del('forum_per_page');
  variable_del('forum_order');
  variable_del('forum_block_num_active');
  variable_del('forum_block_num_new');
  variable_del('node_options_forum');

  field_delete_field('taxonomy_forums');
  // Purge field data now to allow taxonomy module to be uninstalled
  // if this is the only field remaining.
  field_purge_batch(10);
}
```

Your module should do the same, and avoid deleting the fields defined for the content type (if they are not defined from the module), or the content type itself.

Answer (score 0):

[`node_type_get_type()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_type/7) calls [`_node_types_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/_node_types_build/7), which contains the following comment.

```php
// Check for node types from disabled modules and mark their types for removal.
// Types defined by the node module in the database (rather than by a separate
// module using hook_node_info) have a base value of 'node_content'. The isset()
// check prevents errors on old (pre-Drupal 7) databases.
```

Apparently, `_node_types_build()` is not intended to return content types from disabled modules.

Comment: Well, actually this module example was taken from [Pro Drupal 7 Development](http://www.apress.com/9781430228387) book (page 141) with minor changes and it was given errors even then. Clive suggested to use `_node_types_build(TRUE)` before I call `node_type_delete('job_post')` but it didn't help anyway.